# Oracle installation fails due to ORA-00443

Tags: oracle

I hope that you help me to resolve my problem.
I'm trying to install Oracle 11g on RHEL 6.
All prerequisites are ok, but I'm getting such error during step "Creating and starting Oracle instance". The error text is `ORA-00443: background process "DIAG" did not start`

Sometimes installation fails on 8%, sometimes on 44%. It's very strange. I thought it's related to RAM but I have enough memory (10Gb).

I tried to retry installation several times and sometimes it shows me that another background process (not DIAG, but RDBM for example) did not start. It seems that second part of error is random. But the error code ORA-00443 remains the same.

Here are some information from logs which says nothing to me where is the root cause of a problem

```
[Thread-10] [ 2013-12-17 23:04:34.027 EET ] [CloneDBCreationStep.executeImpl:460]  calling zerodbid
[Thread-10] [ 2013-12-17 23:04:41.620 EET ] [CloneDBCreationStep.executeImpl:470]  Shutdown database
[Thread-10] [ 2013-12-17 23:04:41.622 EET ] [CloneDBCreationStep.executeImpl:492]  Startup ......nomount......
[Thread-14] [ 2013-12-17 23:07:03.433 EET ] [BasicStep.handleNonIgnorableError:430]  oracle.sysman.assistants.util.UIMessageHandler@1719f30:messageHandler
[Thread-14] [ 2013-12-17 23:07:03.433 EET ] [BasicStep.handleNonIgnorableError:431]  ORA-00443: background process "DIAG" did not start
```

I tried to find solution within all possible resources, but no luck. Please help to resolve issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there an alert log, or any trace files for the failing processes?

Comment: I think alert log (alert_<SID>.log) should be already created so look there. Also as a wild guess - try disabling SELinux.

Comment: Are there any more errors after the ORA-00433?

Comment: Please login on the same user as you tried install (it was `oracle`, wasn't it?) and update the question with `ulimit -a`.

Answer (score -1):

Your OS is x86 but not amd64?
It seems SGA setting larger than system limit. Set your oracle memory under 2GB.

Comment: 10Gb RAM... I hope the OP is running a 64-bit OS.